# How to change color of an fa icon when PHP Echo error appears?

Tags: php, css, forms, echo, font-awesome

I have a form that displays error messages on a few of the input fields.

The error messages display perfectly, but I am trying to change the color of my fa icon in the field when its error message appears.

So what I want to achieve is that the icon turns red when its error message appears.

I tried

```
<?php echo "<div class='try' style='color: red;'>". $nameErr ."</div>"; ?>
```

but the fa icon is always displayed instead of only appearing with the error message.

**My Form:**

```
<form method="post" name="contact-form" class="contact-form" id="contact-form" role="form" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]);?>">

    <div class="form-input-group">
        <i class="fa fa-male"></i><input type="text" class="" name="name" maxlength="80" placeholder="Full name">
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-group">
        <i class="fa fa-paper-plane"></i><input type="email" name="email" maxlength="30" placeholder="Email">
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-group">
        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i><input type="text" name="telephone" maxlength="15" placeholder="Phone number">
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-group">
        <i class="fa fa-calendar-o"></i><input type="text" name="event_date" maxlength="30" placeholder="Event date">
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-group">
        <i class="fa fa-users"></i><input type="text" name="guests" maxlength="30" placeholder="Guest amount">
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-group">
        <i class="fa fa-bullhorn"></i><input type="text" name="hear_about" maxlength="80" placeholder="How did you hear about us?">
    </div>

    <div class="form-input-group text-container">
        <i class="fa fa-envelope"></i><textarea name="message" class="text" maxlength="1000" cols="25" rows="6" placeholder="Message"></textarea>
    </div>

    <input type="submit" class="btn-fill form-btn" id="contact-submit" name="submit" value="Submit"> 

    <span class="error"><?php echo $nameErr;?></span>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $emailErr;?></span>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $telephoneErr;?></span>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $hear_aboutErr;?></span>
    <span class="error"><?php echo $messageErr;?></span>

</form>
```

**My PHP**

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {

//if(isset($_POST['email'])) {

$subject = 'Website Contact Form Submission';

$message = "
    <html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <table>
    <tr><td>Name:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["name"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Email:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["email"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Telephone:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["telephone"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Event Date:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["event_date"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Guests Amount:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["guests"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Hear About:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["hear_about"]."</td></tr>
    <tr><td>Message:</td><td style=\"color: red;\"> ".$_POST["message"]."</td></tr>
     </table>
    </body>
    </html>
    ";                      


$headers = "MIME-Version: 1.0" . "\r\n";
$headers .= "Content-type:text/html;charset=UTF-8" . "\r\n";

$headers .= "From: ".$_POST["name"]." <".$_POST["email"].">\r\n";
$headers .= "Reply-To: ".$_POST["name"]." <".$_POST["email"].">\r\n";


mail("example@example.com",$subject,$message,$headers);

    $name = $_POST['name']; // required

    $email = $_POST['email']; // required

    $telephone = $_POST['telephone']; // not required

    $event_date = $_POST['event_date']; // not required

    $guests = $_POST['guests']; // not required

    $hear_about = $_POST['hear_about']; // required

    $message = $_POST['message']; // required


// define variables and set to empty values
$nameErr = $emailErr = $telephoneErr = $hear_aboutErr = $messageErr = "";
$name = $email = $telephone = $event_date = $guests = $hear_about = $message = "";

   if (empty($_POST["name"])) {
     $nameErr = "Name is required";
   } else {
     $name = test_input($_POST["name"]);
     // check if name only contains letters and whitespace
     if (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z ]*$/",$name)) {
       $nameErr = "Only letters and white space allowed"; 
     }
   }

// required
   if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
     $emailErr = "Email is required";
   } else {
     $email = test_input($_POST["email"]);
     // check if e-mail address is well-formed
     if (!filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
       $emailErr = "*Invalid email format"; 
     }
   }

// not required
   if (empty($_POST["telephone"])) {
     $telephoneErr = "Incorrect telephone format";
   } else {
     $telephone = test_input($_POST["telephone"]);
     // check if telephone  is well-formed
     if ( preg_match( '/^[+]?([\d]{0,3})?[\(\.\-\s]?([\d]{3})[\)\.\-\s]*([\d]{3})[\.\-\s]?([\d]{4})$/', $string ) ) {
       $telephoneErr = "Invalid telephone format";
     }
   }

// not required
    if (empty($_POST["event_date"])) {
     $event_date = "";
   } else {
     $event_date = test_input($_POST["event_date"]);
   }

// not required
    if (empty($_POST["guests"])) {
     $guests = "";
   } else {
     $guests = test_input($_POST["guests"]);
   } 

// required
    if (empty($_POST["hear_about"])) {
     $hear_aboutErr = "*Please let us know where you heard about us";
   } else {
     $hear_about = test_input($_POST["hear_about"]);
   } 

// required
    if (empty($_POST["message"])) {
    $messageErr = "*Please enter a message";
   } else {
    if (strlen($_POST['message'])<6)
   {
    $messageErr = "*Message should be at least 6 characters";
   }
    else
   {
    $message = test_input($_POST["message"]);
  }
}

}

function test_input($data) {
   $data = trim($data);
   $data = stripslashes($data);
   $data = htmlspecialchars($data);
   return $data;
}

?>
```

**My CSS**

```
.fa-send::before, .fa-paper-plane::before {
    content:"\f1d8";
}
.form .contact-form .form-input-group i::after {
    border-right: 1px solid #e6e9ea;
    content: "";
    height: 30px;
    left: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    width: 1px;
}
.form .contact-form .form-input-group i.fa {
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #3eb489;
    margin-left: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your validation has to be more professional, but as you have chosen this way, just add the following instruction to the styles list of the container div for each input: 
For example, the name part will be as following:

```
<div class="form-input-group" style="<?php echo empty($nameErr)?' ':'color:red;'; ?>">
    <i class="fa fa-male"></i><input type="text" class="" name="name" maxlength="80" placeholder="Full name">
   </div>
```

To have an improved validation, Why don't you use a Javascript Validation as a first validation layer, [Jquery Validation](http://jqueryvalidation.org/) for example. This validation should not replace the backend validation, but it would be the user's first level of validation.

to improve the backend validation interactivity if needed, you may create a Standalone Validation Class that returns Error Messages with error codes, For the font icons colors, distinguish your font icons by a class with the according fields names, and then use one Javascript instruction to assign colors accordingly.

Comment: How do you feel my validation should be more professional? Also, the method you proposed, how does this change the color of the icon?

Comment: So you are saying I should place the echo within the style of the containing div to change it?

Comment: Yes, this is a hard-coded option, but I prefer to add a distinguing class to every containing div, and at the end of the file, write some Javascript code that assigns the red color to the divs that contain any errors.

To assign the red color, instead of adding an inline color, You would add the following class to your CSS:  .red_colored{color:red}   and add this class to any element you like to paint in red.

Comment: This worked. I had to just make a few tweaks to get it to work properly. Because I was assigning the fa icon's color in `.form .contact-form .form-input-group i.fa` it was overwriting your method, so I have assigned the color elsewhere and it now works.

Comment: About the JS Validation, I have no idea how to do this. I would love to rather assign their colors through that kind of script but my knowledge is extremely limited about it (more like non-existent). Could you perhaps help me get there. I would love to get it right!

Comment: I would never be more clear and simple than the following link: http://www.sitepoint.com/basic-jquery-form-validation-tutorial/ 
OR 
http://code.runnable.com/UZJ24Io3XEw2AABU/how-to-validate-forms-in-jquery-for-validation

Comment: This is great. Thanks so much. I will try my hand at them. I appreciate it.